# How to write Sitemesh configuration withouw WEB.XML

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, sitemesh

When the project was launched, the mesh site worked in web.xml. But now I want to run it without web.xml and i deleted him. I wrote the code it seems to be correct, but you can tell where you made a mistake or did not write correctly.
He doesn't show me sitemesh menu template

```
package adil.java.schoolmaven.config;

import org.sitemesh.builder.SiteMeshFilterBuilder;
import org.sitemesh.config.ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter;

public class MySiteMeshFilter extends ConfigurableSiteMeshFilter {

  @Override
  protected void applyCustomConfiguration(SiteMeshFilterBuilder builder) {

            builder.addDecoratorPath("/*", "/WEB-INF/decorators/homeDecorator.jsp") 

           .addDecoratorPath("/allStudents", "/WEB-INF/decorators/homeDecorator.jsp")
           .addDecoratorPath("/addStudents", "/WEB-INF/decorators/addStudentDecorator.jsp");




  }

}
```

Servlet Initializer

```
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size}")

    private int maxFileSize;

    @Value("${spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size}")

    private int maxRequestSize;

    @Autowired

    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{HibernateConfig.class/*, SecurityConfig.class*/};

    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{WebMvcConfig.class};

    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {

        return new String[]{"/"};

    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {

        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{characterEncodingFilter, new SiteMeshFilter()};
    }


  }
```